# Inflection points of $|x^2-2x|$

Tags: calculus

I found second derivative: $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(|x^2 - 2 x|) = \frac{(2 (x - 2) x)}{|(x - 2) x|} + 4 δ(x - 2) + 4 δ(x)$

How do I solve this equation?

Comment: Do you really want to solve that equation, or just to find the inflection points?  If it’s the latter, I would use the fact that $(x-1)^2-1=x^2-2x$ to graph $|x^2-2x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=|x^2-2x|=\begin{cases}x^2-2x\;,&x(x-2)\ge0\iff x\le0\,\,or\,\,x\ge2\\{}\\-x^2+2x, &0<x<2\end{cases}$$

so

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x-2\implies f''=2\,&x\in(-\infty,0]\cup[2,\infty)\\{}\\-2x+2\implies f''=-2,&x\in(0,2)\end{cases}$$

The second derivative exists everywehre and is different from zero ...**except** at $\;x=0,2\;$ . Try now to finish the argument.